# In Numbers, how can I show a formula instead of the result?

Tags: numbers

I want selected cells to show the formula instead of the result of the formula, for example cells C4 and D4 here.

[image: Cell C4 contains "=B4+1" rather than the numerical result of adding 1 to the value in B4.]

If the cell is formatted as text *before* I enter the formula, then the formula remains text.  However, selecting text format after the formula has been computed has no effect.

Comment: There is no easy way to do this, but the formula is shown at the bottom of the Numbers-window, so why do you want to see it in the cell itself?

Comment: I assigned my class a problem requiring them to build a spreadsheet, and I wanted to show my solution.  Showing the formulas in selected cells would illustrate how the numerical results were obtained.

Comment: Is there no possibility, yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly...

- Enter the formula in the cell normally.
- In the formula box dropdown, select **Convert Formula to Text in Cell**

This will replace the formula result with the formula.

**Warning:** This will replace the formula with text so if any other cell's formula is dependent on the converted cell it will break.

[image: Convert Formula to Text in Cell]

[image: Animation showing conversion of formula to text]